# gradle problem when i install flutter_webview packages

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

hey i'm trying to create a webview in my Flutter app but when i installing  flutter_webview plugin  i got this problems with gradle :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

i had try with multi  version in flutter_webview and the same problem

Comment: In "android/app/build.gradle" set "multiDexEnabled true"

Comment: i did it but not think change stay same error :(